# params[:token] not set with devise

Tags: ruby, devise, token, parameters

I'm trying to implement Devise but new to it.

When I request .../api/v1/projects.json, I get 'undefined method admin? for nil:NilClass', which I'm assuming happens because params[:token] is not being set:

```
class Api::V1::ProjectsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def index
    respond_with(Project.for(current_user))
  end
end
```

## --

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def self.for(user)
    user.admin? ? Project : Project.readable_by(user)
  end
end
```

## --

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :ensure_authentication_token

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :token_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable 
  ...

end
```

## --

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user

  respond_to :json

  private

    def authenticate_user
      @current_user = User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:token])
    end

    def current_user
      @current_user
    end

end
```

Does anyone know how/where to set params[:token] with Devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I misunderstood the documentation, and token is passed in through the URL:
.../api/v1/projects.json?token=s28seWhpPVWkhMU7sszM

Problem solved, I guess.